# Roadmap Process software

Tags: software-recommendation

I am looking for an app that can be used to create a roadmap of all the processes a company or a development team needs to achieve over a course of time. If the app comes with an output as svg it would be excellent, if not, not big deal. It is actually something like calligraplan and planner but more in the style of something that can do one of the following types of roadmaps:

[image]

Or like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Gephi**](https://gephi.org/)

Gephi is a Open Source Visualization tool.

It can do analyze data and result visual statistics.

Can download from [gephi.org](http://gephi.org/users/download/).